# How can I grab the error from javascript console in chromium

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a page for students to be able to enter code in a textarea to solve javscript programming exercise. But I want the user to get errors when their code doesn't work. eg: line number or syntax error, etc. The problem is I don't know how to grab the error from javascript console. Or if that's even possible. How could I get the error from code entered in javascript? Here's the skeleton page I'm working on. It is a basic function to get the code from a textarea and using eval send it to console. But I need to also grab when there's an error from the code... can some one help? thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JScript Page</title>
  <script>
    function jstest() {
      var code = document.getElementById("textArea").value;
      console.log(eval(code));
      return false;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Enter your code here!</h2>
  <form>
    <textarea rows="7" cols="50" id="textArea">
</textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return jstest();">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `try { ... } catch(e) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can add next script to your document. It will catch all the errors and show them as alert messages

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onerror = function(message, url, lineNumber) {
    alert("Error: "+message+" in "+url+" at line "+lineNumber);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Override console error to show all developer console errors to the user.

```
console.myError = console.error;

console.error = function (message) {
    console.myError(message);
    document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML = message;
}
```

Comment: should I put the code in a separate function than jstest() function...  when console.log(eval(code)) is call... should I redirect the error before this call or after. Thanks